# AWS SSM Automation Document with allowed values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I started to use Automation Document form AWS System Manager (SSM) but I need to define the AMI-id, I will like to create a dropdown list in order to provide only the available AMI's based on the region.

- So far I need to be aware which AMI's ids are available in that region.
- I will like to avoid the manual process of copy/paste.
- Also, I don't want to type the AMI's id.

I know the only allowed types of SSM Parameters are **String** or **StringList**.

I tested with allowed values but that didn't work at all:

### Document example:

```
{
   "description":"Systems Manager Automation Demo - Patch and Create a New AMI",
   "schemaVersion":"0.3",
   "assumeRole":"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/AutomationServiceRole",
   "parameters":{
      "AMIID":{
         "type":"String",
         "description":"Instance to value",
         "allowedValues" : [ "ami-5648ad2c", "ami-5648ad33", "ami-5238ad2c", "ami-5238ad2c" ]
      }
   },
   "mainSteps":[
      {
         "name":"launchInstances",
         "action":"aws:runInstances",
         "timeoutSeconds":1200,
         "maxAttempts":1,
         "onFailure":"Abort",
         "inputs":{
            "ImageId":"{{ AMIID }}",
            "InstanceType":"t2.micro",
            "KeyName":"accenture",
            "MinInstanceCount":1,
            "MaxInstanceCount":1,
            "IamInstanceProfileName":"ManagedAMIProfile"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```